# How to propagate tree nodes in Python

Tags: python, tree, reduce

I am dealing with a tree structure in a Python program.
Each node in a tree has a dictionary "sons", whose keys hold arc information, and values
are the son nodes. The question is to propagate a list of nodes to all their sons.
I use:

```
current_nodes = reduce(lambda s,x:s+x, map(lambda node:node.sons.values(),current_nodes),[])
```

Where `current_nodes` is the initial (and updated) list of nodes.

My program spends most time executing this reduce operation. Is there a faster way to implement that?

Thank you!

EDIT: 
Hi, Just let you know that the code:
`sum((node.sons.values() for node in current_nodes), [])`
although pythonic, is not really significantly faster -- if the list of nodes
is long (>20000), the propagation slows down unproportionally, actually, very slow. I don't know why.

Then I define:

```
def Ext(nodes)
    l=[]
    for node in nodes:
        l.extend(node.sons.values())
    return l
```

Then I use: `current_node = Ext(current_node)`.
This approach is actually much faster. I guess sum() function is not as efficient as a list's extend method when handling list concatenation.

Comment: why you're using that ugly `reduce` when `sum` does the job? Same thing to that ugly `map`: `List comprehensions` FTW

Comment: Can sum concatenate a list of lists?

Comment: I got it. sum([node.sons.values() for node in current_nodes],[])

Comment: Yep, `sum` needs a base element to serve as the "accumulator" (in case the sequence is empty, and so that the first element of a non-empty sequence doesn't need special handling), which defaults to `0`, but can be replaced. To sum lists, you just start with an empty list. However, `sum` will arbitrarily refuse to `sum(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], '')`, and tell you to use the `''.join` idiom instead. Personally I think this was a rather overzealous application of TSBOWTDI :(

Comment: BTW, "children" is the canonical name for such a data member...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(node.sons.values() for node in current_nodes))
```

Should be faster. `map` and `reduce` on `lambda`s are slow. I don't know how fast `chain` is; you could try

```
sum((node.sons.values() for node in current_nodes), [])
```

as well.

Comment: I thought you were taking a break ;)

Comment: I'm logging in once a day to work on my flag weight and I happened to see this :)